# Trying to pass "var app" into a function

Tags: javascript

I was trying to do an uploader application with the help of AJAX.
I was doing like [here](https://youtu.be/BoU0JZNQNnA?t=50s)

```
var app = app || {};

(function(0) {
    // can be used 'app.functionName();'
}(app));
```

But I don't really understand what it is done here.
Could anybody explain me this? :/

Comment: You don't need to pass `app` as it is **global**, it can be accessed from anywhere

Comment: Really this is just the basics of Javascript, so you may want to take a step back and review that. You are looking at a "Immediately-invoked function expression" and is consider a good practice as is enclosing the scope of your function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression As for the first part is just making sure that "app" is already defined and if is not it will create an empty object to work with. That is why I presume the tutorial is declaring app even is global, just to be sure that is defined before using it.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just didn't know the name of the functions...
I couldn't find them at MozillaDN.
Anyway, I know the answer now so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain the function part:

```
function callMe(param){
    console.log(param);
}

(function callMeNow(param){
    console.log(param);
})({}); // logs [object Object]
callMe({}) // logs [object Object]
```

As you can see, as soon as `callMeNow` is defined, it runs first.

Because of this, people can do cool things like:

```
var app = (function callMeNow(param){ // creates its own scope
    var privateVariable = 21;
    var privateFunc = function(){
        return privateVariable
    };
    param.getSecretNumber = privateFunc
    return param;
})({});

console.log(app.getSecretNumber()) // logs 21
```

Answer (score 0):

The 0 is supposed to be an o. This allows you to access what is inside app, via the alias o.